# efficient way to check database connection?

Tags: database, grails, grails-2.2

What is the fastest database connection check in grails? I need to create an endpoint which will be called again and again by a script so this needs to be efficient. The database goes down fom time to time and this script will call this api that will return a status code. Based on this status code the bot will know the database is down. If it is 200 then everything is ok.

So i need to check if database connection is intact in a very efficient manner. Since the call happens every few seconds what is the fastest way to check for database status. My thought is to use a simple gorm query like  Status.read(1). If there is an exception then return a non 200 status code. Is there a more efficient way for a quick database status check?

I appreciate any insights. I am using Grails 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just avoid using GORM all together and just use a super simple database query like `SELECT 1`? Putting this into a service it might look like something like this:

```
package my.example

class MyService {

    def dataSource
    def someTimeoutValue = 1000

    boolean isDatabaseThere() {
        try {
            dataSource.connection.isValid(someTimeoutValue)
            return true // everything is okay
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false // everything is not okay
        }
    }
}
```

Pardon any typos or anything, that was written on the fly.

Comment: thanks. one question. what is dataSource? is it injected in service. please note i am using grails 2.2. Is that supported by grails 2.2?

Comment: dataSource is the name of the database data source as defined in Datasource.groovy. The default data source is named `dataSource`. This should work in Grails 2.x

Comment: I don't think you need to create an `Sql` instance for this.  Would `dataSource.connection.isValid(someTimeoutValue)` be more efficient and accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown That's a very good point. I suppose that would require less resources at least. Do you mind if I edit the answer to reflect that?

Comment: for this simple check i am thinking putting the check logic in controller itself so i wonder how efficient would it be to use def ds = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('dataSource') inside checkStatus() method in controller. The checkStatus will be called every few seconds.

Comment: @kofhearts Why would you do that instead of `def dataSource` in the controller (just like the service)? There is no reason to resolve the `dataSource` every call. That's not efficient at all. Also, I'd still put all of this logic in a service and call the service from a controller, but then that's just me.

Comment: please make sure you close the connection as well.